# Static DataService class vs. IRepository<T>?

Tags: service, interface, static

I am just studying the code of Sacha Barbers MVVM framework Chinch and I saw this in the xxxViewModel.cs file:

```
DataService.FetchAllOrders(CurrentCustomer.CustomerId.DataValue);
```

DataService is a Static class.  Being a junior dev I am only used to Interfaces with Data services. Why is that class static?

Or do you think he made it just for the example?

So is that a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fairness, I don't know what's going on in FetchAllOrders - it might be programmed to behave well.

In practical experience, I've seen static classes used poorly to maintain the infrastructure needed to do data access.  I say "poorly" because these implementations (that I've seen) were not made thread-safe.  When the code was deployed to a multi-user environment (such as a web application), it exploded.

- Use static classes for classes that contain no state (and are threadsafe as a result).  Classes with just methods, for example.
- Use static classes for classes where it is intended to make access serial with locks (threadsafe).
- Use static classes in throw-away code to avoid the design overhead of constructing/maintaining/passing instances.

Look into the .net framework and see which classes Microsoft made static and meditate on why.

Comment: Well a repository has only methods to get and pass data from database/context. So I think using a static DataAccess class can be okish.